# Is it Possible to Obtain Rudin-Style LaTeX Document Format?

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontsize, font-encodings

I'm trying to obtain some format settings (or copyable code) for LaTeX documents.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (a book I'm sure many people here have seen before).

While I'm sure many people find the out-dated typeset rather ugly, I personally fell in love with it when I personally used this text as an undergraduate.

Now that I am in graduate school, I am finding myself creating mathematical documents in LaTeX much more frequently, and I have been trying to emulate this style for some time now.  I know that it is typeset in "Times Roman" (according to the publisher), but those are all the details.

I have also noticed that there are other texts which have a similar look, yet are slightly different (for example, if you look at the other texts in Rudin's series, you'll notice slight changes, and this is probably a reflection of more modern type-set and changes to the font itself over the years).  What particularly attracts me is the darkened font style (as if everything is bold, and what is bold is bold 2x).

Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

This is taken out of Zygmund and Wheedon's text on measure and integration theory.  The fonts are clearly quite similar, yet the ladder is "lighter" and not as "thick" as the former.

Anyway, I realize getting a format identical to Rudin's is probably impossible, so I would of course be happy with something as close as possible to the text formatting in Rudin.

Also, I know that it is off topic here, but I'm also interested in obtaining similar text formatting for my online blog, which has full HTML/CSS styling customization, so if somebody who is kind enough to help with the LaTeX happens to have a corresponding CSS design, that would be awesome!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What features of the text are you unable to reproduce? If you add an example code showing your attempt to solve the problem, others will probably suggest improvements.

Comment: Sure.  The only thing that I was able to come up with is

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

coupled with 10pt font.  It looks reasonably close to Rudin's text, but for instance, the text is very light in comparison, and overall it's just "different" if that makes sense.

Comment: @JTian: are you interested in the font? The proof environment? The subsection format? The equation numbering? The margin formatting? Specifically, what are you interested in? You appear to only talk about font, so is that what you're really asking about? (There's more to typography than just the font, you know!)

Comment: Hehe, yes very true.

Comment: I like it all, actually.  The theorem environments, however, I've already been able to emulate myself(:  Same goes with the margins and environment counters.  It really is just the text formatting that I can't seem to perfectly emulate (to my perhaps unrealistic satisfaction).  Somehow the characters are "thicker," which is I guess the only reasson it looks so much more different to me.  But is that just a side-effect from the publisher, or is it a style that can be done in LaTeX formatting?

Comment: this is just a guess, but it's quite likely that even if the book was reproduced by offset, the master copy was printed from metal type.  (i can find references to three editions, published in 1953, 1964, and 1976.  at least the first two editions would definitely have been set in metal type.)  that has the effect known as "ink spread", which makes the print look heavier.  digital type is more often designed to conform to the original shapes of the uninked metal type, which is the main reason why even the same design will print thinner/lighter.

Comment: I think we'd need a much more concrete question than 'reproduce this style'. I'd suggest asking some focussed questions on particular details you are struggling with.